# WiFi P2P Group with custom DNS in android

Tags: dns, p2p, wifi-direct

I want to create a group using the createGroup() method. The P2P group has the gateway and DNS set to 192.168.49.1. I want to set the DNS to a custom IP rather than what is assigned by the method. How is this possible??

My ultimate aim is to give internet connectivity to the P2P group.

Comment: It is my impression that the API specifically prevents it. If anyone finds a way, please post here :)